# Parsing a log into record blocks with Powershell RegEx DOTALL and a lookbehind assertion

Tags: regex, powershell-4.0, lookbehind

This question applies to the task of parsing a very large unstructured log file using Powershell 4.0, applying a regular expression with a look behind assertion, and a dotall modifier.

A single record in the log documents a process on several lines of various transaction attempts. I want to be able to split up the log into discrete records using starting and ending lines that can be identified by a success message. The success message marks the end of a record being processed. The line that follows is always the start of a new record.

Once the log is broken up into an array of discrete records, I will then more confidently be able to grab critical pieces of data from each record. That's the current logic, anyway - but I'm not concerned with this part of the process for now. I'll do that later.

A highly-simplified chunk of the log looks like this:

```
20151120 11:10:31 UPDATE ARI has value [].
20151120 11:10:31 ERROR returning from process_updid with invalid NICS query - no ARI code: []..
20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:31 UPDATE Tag SSN has value [].
20151120 11:10:31 UPDATE Tag SOC has value [].

20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:31 ONE This is some random text that I just made up.
20151120 11:10:31 TWO This is more random text that I just made up.

20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:31 THREE This is additional random text that I just made up.
20151120 11:10:31 FOUR This is still more random text that I just made up.
```

The message line that alerts a reader to the end of a process, and the start of a new record appears like this:

```
20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
```

Everything after that line, until the next success message is a complete record.

The regular expression pattern that I have so far is:

```
(?<=\d{8}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sINFO transaction processed successfully\.)(?s)(.+)
```

This pattern correctly identifies the first success message, but then includes subsequent success messages in that first record, and repeats the same record for a second match. The (.+) expression is grabbing too much. I tried an ungreedy (+?) quantifier - with no match; as well as a lookahead assertion to identify a stopping point at the next success message - again no joy.

The full Powershell code is:

```
Clear-Host

$s = @"
20151120 11:10:31 UPDATE ARI has value [].
20151120 11:10:31 ERROR returning from process_updid with invalid NICS query - no ARI code: []..
20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:31 UPDATE Tag SSN has value [].
20151120 11:10:31 UPDATE Tag SOC has value [].

20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:31 ONE This is some random text that I just made up.
20151120 11:10:31 TWO This is more random text that I just made up.

20151120 11:10:31 INFO transaction processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:31 THREE This is additional random text that I just made up.
20151120 11:10:31 FOUR This is still more random text that I just made up.
"@

$p = "(?<=\d{8}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sINFO transaction processed successfully\.)(?s)(.+)"

$s | Select-String $p -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches}
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind the lookbehind, just use this:

```
(?:\d{8}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?!INFO transaction processed successfully\.).+\n?)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eJ5eB6/1)

It matches one or more lines that don't match the pattern of a success message.  If you're not sure how to approach a problem, lookbehind should never be the first tool you reach for.  Usually it just makes the job more difficult.  DOTALL/Singleline mode does too, to a lesser extent, plus it makes you more vulnerable to never-ending matches.

Another option is to Split on a pattern that *does* match a success message:

```
\s*\d{8}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\sINFO transaction processed successfully\.\s*
```

Comment: A very interesting and new approach to me, Alan. The first pattern works beautifully.

I'm not quite understanding how it works well enough to replicate. There's a passive group, a negative look ahead assertion, a 1 or more wild card dot bounded by a line return, and a 1 or more quantifier.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the demo example. I love [RegEx101.com](http://Regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank you, @alan-moore, for the suggestion to split the multi-line block of text into an array. I couldn't get that example to work, but went back to the documentation where I found a multiline -split example that I could expand upon.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811(v=wps.630).aspx

```
$p = "(.+INFO.+?processed successfully\..+\n)"

$s -split $p, 0, "multiline"
```

This solution seems to work. The text block is an anonymized fragment of the actual log I'm trying to parse.

```
<#
Working on the example pattern provided here by Alan Moore:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33929429/2120780
#>

Clear-Host

<#
This is an anonymized, unstructured actual log in which a record is comprised of 
returns from various transactions, and those return messages can span multiple lines.
For ease in identifying starting and ending lines, in record blocks, 
## START ##  and ## END ## text was inserted.
#>

$s = @"
20151120 11:00:01 INFO Nightly NICS Criminal Synchronization began execution.
20151120 11:00:01 INFO Connected to Database OK.
20151120 11:00:01 INFO Connected to SMEL.
20151120 11:00:01 INFO In criminal_sequence_sync_protocolin state 1.
20151120 11:10:24 INFO {call dbo.lems_check_identifiers} procedure call successfull.
20151120 11:10:24 INFO process_checkid processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:24 ## START: 1 ## INFO criminal_sequence_sync_protocol new state=2, transaction count=564.
20151120 11:10:57 UPDATE Tag NSS has value [].
20151120 11:10:57 UPDATE Tag COS has value [].
20151120 11:10:57 UPDATE Tag DIS has value [0000123456].
20151120 11:10:57 UPDATE Tag ARI has value [MIRC1234567].
20151120 11:10:57 UPDATE SMIC.C5.LA012345J.DIS/0000123456.PUR/C.REQ/SMIC MIRC1234567.
20151120 11:10:58 RESPONSE SMIC-NC.ACK 123456B021 SMIC-NC  755B4F SMIC-NC  37B021 20151120 11:10:51

.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO MSN of message to SMEL is <123456B021>.
20151120 11:10:58 RESPONSE SMIC-NC.MSG 123456B021 SMIC-NC  755B50 CCHC     89140F 20151120 11:10:51
LA012345J.
CTL/
ATN/

C5.LA012345J..123456B021..
                     *****REQUESTED HCC DIS NOT FOUND*****.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO MSN of message from SMEL is <123456B021>.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO In criminal_sequence_sync_protocolin state 2.
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE Tag ATN has value [].
20151120 11:10:58 INFO ATN read from query: [], w/ length: 0.
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE ATN from C5 response has value [].
20151120 11:10:58 INFO ATN read from C5 response: [], w/ length: 0.
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE ARI has value [].
20151120 11:10:58 ## END 1 ## ERROR returning from process_updid with invalid SCIN query - no ARI code: []..
20151120 11:10:58 INFO process_updid processed successfully.
20151120 11:35:13 ## START 2 ## UPDATE SMIC-NC.EDP.LA012345J.NAM/SADDLER,BELL.SEX/M.RAC/B.DOB/19700101.PCA/A1.ARI/MIRC1234567.DNY/CONVICTED OF 15 1403 B.OCA/0123456.SOR/LA.MIS/CONFIRM RECORD AT CSAL 123-456-7890 OR PAGER 123-456-7890.
20151120 11:35:13 RESPONSE SMIC-NC.ACK 123456B247 SMIC-NC  755FA8 SMIC-NC  37B247 20151120 11:35:07

.
20151120 11:35:13 INFO MSN of message to SMEL is <123456B247>.
20151120 11:35:14 RESPONSE SMIC-NC.MSG 123456B247 SMIC-NC  755FA9 NC2K     8E261D 20151120 11:35:07
LA012345J
CTL/
ATN/

6L01123456B2472EDP 
LA012345J
REJECT    MKE/EDP
NAM/SADDLER,BELL.SEX/M.RAC/B.DOB/19700101.SOR/LA.PCA/A1.
ARI/MIRC1234567.OCA/0123456.DNY/CONVICTED OF 15 1403 B.
MIS/CONFIRM RECORD AT CSAL 123-456-7890 OR PAGER 123-456-7890

FOR THE FOLLOWING REASON(S)
 DUPLICATE RECORD
SCIN-END.
20151120 11:35:14 INFO MSN of message from SMEL is <123456B247>.
20151120 11:35:14 INFO In criminal_sequence_sync_protocolin state 4.
20151120 11:35:14 ## END 2 ## ERROR SCIN REJECT msg received by process_updc - move onto next msg.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO process_updid processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:58 ## START 3 ## UPDATE Tag SSN has value [123456789].
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE Tag ARI has value [CRIM1234567].
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE SIMC.C4.LA012345J.COS/123456789.PUR/C.ATN/SIMC MIRC1234567.
20151120 11:10:58 RESPONSE SIMC-NC.ACK 123456B022 SIMC-NC  755B51 SIMC-NC  37B022 20151120 11:10:51

.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO MSN of message to SMEL is <123456B022>.
20151120 11:10:58 RESPONSE SIMC-NC.MSG 123456B022 SIMC-NC  755B52 CCHC     123450 20151120 11:10:52
LA012345J.
CTL/
ATN/SIMC MIRC1234567

C4.LA012345J..123456B022.SIMC MIRC1234567.
 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/ A    NS/ ---
 RAC/ W SEX/ F HGT/ 501 WGT/ 120  HAI/ BRO EYE/ BRO POB/ LA DOB/ 01-01-1970
 AUTO/ Y   COS/           OLN/                           OLS/ 
 LID/  ORI/ LA0530000 FBI/ 123456FA8
 DIS/ 0001234567 STAT/ 
 FPH1/ 

 FPH2/                            008 ALIASES
       001 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/ A        SUF/ 
       002 LNM/ STEVENS              FNM/ JANE          MIN/ A        SUF/ 
       003 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/          SUF/ 
       004 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/ A        SUF/ 
       005 LNM/ SMYTH             FNM/ JENNIFER          MIN/ A        SUF/ 
       006 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/          SUF/ 
       007 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/          SUF/ 
       008 LNM/ SMITH             FNM/ JENNIE          MIN/ A        SUF/ 
.
C5.LA012345J..123456B030.. 11/20/2015 11:11:43                                  
REQUESTED BY: SIMC MIRC1234560

                           S T A T E  CRIMINAL HISTORY
                            *FOR AUTHORIZED USE ONLY*
                 (FINGERPRINTS ARE NECESSARY FOR A POSITIVE ID)

INVESTIGATIVE REPORT                                      CONFIDENTIAL RECORDS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CRIMINAL RECORD OF: SMITH, JENNIE A                                 FBI: 123456HC2
STATE ID: 0001234567    BIRTH DATE: 01/01/1970     PLACE: TN      DOC: 
RACE: W         HEIGHT:  5' 5"          HAIR: BLK                 DNA ON FILE:YES
SEX:  F         WEIGHT: 145             EYES: BRN
SSN: 123456789  OLS/OLN:                                          III: SSO
STATUS: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARREST DATE: 01/12/2005                                    LID: 01234567
AGENCY: CLARKSTOWN, MS PD (LA0123456)                         AFIS ATN: 123456789012
   NAME: SMITH, JENNIE A

CHARGE 1                                                   COUNTS 1
   R.S. 14:67A(FELONY) F THEFT CHARGE

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
** TO BE CONTINUED **.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO MSN of message from SMEL is <123456B022>.
20151120 11:10:58 INFO In criminal_sequence_sync_protocolin state 2.
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE Tag ATN has value [SIMC MIRC1234567].
20151120 11:10:58 INFO ATN read from query: [SIMC MIRC1234567], w/ length: 20.
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE ARI has value [CRIM1234567].
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE Tag COS has value [].
20151120 11:10:58 UPDATE Tag DIS has value [0001234567].
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE {call dbo.lems_update_id_check_fields ('CRIM1234567', 'COS', 'N', '20151120')} update procedure call successfull.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE {call dbo.lems_update_id_check_fields ('CRIM1234567', 'DIS', 'N', '20151120')} update procedure call successfull.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [STEVENS].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [STEVENS], w/ length: 7.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE LNM has value [SMITH].
20151120 11:10:59 INFO LNM read from SNIC response: [SMITH], w/ length: 8.
20151120 11:10:59 ERROR No data found for given names.
20151120 11:10:59 INFO  SELECT DIS FROM CRIMINALS WHERE  DIS = '0001234567'  AND UPPER(LNAME) IN ( 'SMITH' , 'SMITH' , 'STEVENS' , 'SMITH' , 'SMITH' , 'SMITH' , 'SMITH' , 'SMITH' , 'SMITH' )  
 name and DIS check done, name_match N .
20151120 11:10:59 ## END 3 ## UPDATE {call dbo.lems_update_id_check_fields ('CRIM1234567', 'LNM', 'N', '20151120')} update procedure call successfull.
20151120 11:10:59 INFO process_updid processed successfully.
20151120 11:10:59 ## START 4 ## UPDATE Tag NSS has value [].
20151120 11:10:59 UPDATE Tag COS has value [].
"@

$p = "(.+INFO.+?processed successfully\..+\n)"

$s -split $p, 0, "multiline"
```

Comment: FYI, there's an error on that page you linked to.  Singleline mode is *not* the opposite of Multiline mode, they are *not* mutually exclusive, and Singleline mode is *not* the default.  This is why some flavors use the name DOTALL instead of Singleline, to emphasize that it changes the behavior of the dot and nothing else.  Multiline mode only affects the anchors, so it has no effect on your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extra little tip on splitting blocks of text. Suppose the use case requires, instead of dropping the line on which the blocks are split, keeping the line. Suppose the line that splits a block of text isn't superfluous, but critical to a record. When you want to keep the line on which a block of text is being split, that's a good use for a lookahead expression.

Here's a very simple example. The use case would be one in which the "start" line is the first line of a new record in the larger block of text:

```
Clear-Host

$s = @"
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 start
5 five
6 six
7 seven
"@

$p = "(?=\d\sstart)"
$records = $s | Select-String $p -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value}
#$records = [regex]::split($s, $p, "MULTILINE")
$records = [regex]::split($s, $p)

Foreach($r in $records) 
{
    $r
}
```

The code sample above produces two blocks of text, in my use case, each split block is a record block comprised of several lines that contain related information.

```
1 one
2 two
3 three

4 start
5 five
6 six
7 seven
```

The magic sauce is the (?=) look ahead expression in the pattern. It parses the block of text at the character immediately preceding the matching lookahead pattern, capturing the start row as part of the split second block of text. Note that there's a perhaps confusing bit in there - a \s space expression in front of the literal "start" text:

```
$p = "(?=\d\sstart)"
```

Remove the lookahead expression, but leave the grouping parentheses, and you end up with three blocks of text the second of which is a start row, but separated from the rest of the lines below it.

```
$p = "(\d\sstart)"
```

Remove the lookahead expression, and remove the grouping parentheses, and two blocks of text are produced, with the start row now removed.

```
$p = "\d\sstart"
```

Note that, as @alan-moore indicated, the "multiline" modifier doesn't help. It doesn't hurt in this example, but neither does it help. Better to just remove it. There's a commented line in the code block above to test that conclusion.